# Using MongoDB's for storing files of size est. 500KB

Tags: mongodb

In GridFS FAQ there is said that one should store in aforementioned GridFS files of size >16MB. I have a lot of files ~500KB.

Question is: which approach is more efficient - storing files' content inside document or storing file itself in GridFS? Should I consider other approaches?

Comment: What is the max size for your files? As per the GridFS docs, it breaks files up into chunks and then stores those chunks in one collection and metadata in another. If your files are all well within the 16MB limit then I would expect storing/retrieving will be faster and more space efficient.

Comment: The docs I was referring to above are available at: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/

Comment: As I mentioned in OP, mostly ~500KB. Estimated *max* size is at most 1MB.

What did you mean by "storing/retrieving"? Reading file contents into document and forming a new file than? I suspect files to be retrieved ~10 000 times per hour. Is it efficient - to create a new file each time?

Comment: By "storing/rerieving" I mean writing the file contents into a document and then retrieving. By efficient can you clarify which aspect your are looking at? From the MongoDB perspective this will just be reading and writing documents of the file size and should be just as efficient as normal MongoDB operation. If you are talking about retrieving and then writing to disk each time you retrieve then it will be dependent on the performance of your disk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As for efficiency, either approach is the same. GridFS is implemented at the driver level by paging your >16MB data across multiple documents. MongoDB is unaware that you're storing a "file", it just knows how to store documents and doesn't ask questions.

So, depending on your driver (PHP/NodeJS/Ruby), you may find some metadata features nice and opt to use GridFS because of that. Otherwise, if you are absolutely sure a document will not be larger than 16MB, storing the raw content in the document should be fairly simple and just as fast (or faster).

Generally, I'd recommend against storing files in the database. It can have a negative impact on your working set and overall speed.